# Sequence of indicator functions have $L^2$-convergent subsequence.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I'd like to know if the following statement is true:

*Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and $(A_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of measurable sets. Then, there exists a measurable set $A$ and a subsequence $(A_{n_k})_{k\geq1}$ such that $\chi_{A_{n_k}}$ converges to $\chi_A$ in the $L^2(\mu)$ norm.*

I think a have a proof, which I present below, but I am not sure if it is correct.

*Proof:*
First, we note that, since $\mu$ is a probability measure, the sequence $(\chi_{A_n})_{n\geq1}$ is bounded in the $L^2(\mu)$ norm.
Hence, there exists a weak-convergent subsequence $(\chi_{A_{n_k}})_{k\geq1}$.
Let $f$ be the weak limit.

We claim that $f = \chi_A$ for some measurable set $A$.
To prove this, it is enough to show that $f$ assumes only the values $0$ or $1$ almost surely.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $C_\varepsilon = \{x : f(x) \geq 1+\varepsilon\}$.
Then, $C_\varepsilon$ is measurable and so, by the weak convergence,
$$ \int \chi_{A_{n_k}} \chi_{C_\varepsilon} d\mu \longrightarrow 
\int_{C_\varepsilon} f d\mu \geq (1+\varepsilon) \mu(C_\varepsilon); $$
therefore,
$$\mu(C_\varepsilon) \geq \lim_k \mu(A_{n_k} \cap C_\varepsilon) =
\int \chi_{A_{n_k}} \chi_{C_\varepsilon} d\mu \geq (1+\varepsilon)\mu(C_\varepsilon). $$
This is only possible if $\mu(C_\varepsilon) = 0$, that is, if $f \leq 1+\varepsilon$ almost surely.
Hence, $f \leq 1$ almost surely.

A similar argument shows that $f \geq 0$ a.s.
We conclude that
$$ 0 \leq f \leq 1 \enspace \text{almost surely.} $$
We are going to prove that $f = \chi_A$, where $A = \limsup_{k\to+\infty} A_{n_k} = \bigcap_{\ell \geq 1} \bigcup_{k > \ell} A_{n_k}$.

Let $B_k = \bigcup_{\ell > k} A_{n_k}$.
The weak convergence gives
$$ \int_{B_\ell} f d\mu = 
\lim_{k\to+\infty} \mu(A_{n_k} \cap B_\ell) =
\lim_{k\to+\infty} \mu(A_{n_k}) =\!: \delta, $$
where in the last step we used that $A_{n_k} \subseteq B_\ell$ for all big enough $k$.
Now, by the weak convergence, $\int f d\mu = \delta$, so
$$ \int_{B_\ell} f d\mu = \int f d\mu = \delta. $$
Being this valid for all $\ell$, we get, as $\mu$ is of probability, that
$$ \int_A f d\mu = \int d\mu = \delta. \qquad (1) $$
Since $0 \leq f \leq 1$, we deduce that $f = 0$ in $A^c$.

Observe now that Faout's Lemma implies that $\mu(A) \leq \limsup_{k\to+\infty} \mu(A_{n_k}) = \delta$ **EDIT: there is an error here**.
Combining this with (1) yields that $f = 1$ in $A$.
We conclude that $f = \chi_A$.

We now use the claim to prove the initial statement.
First, observe that
$$ \|\chi_A - \chi_{A_{n_k}}\|_{L^2(\mu)} = 
\int |\chi_A - \chi_{A_{n_k}}| d\mu =
\mu(A \triangle A_{n_k}) \\ = 
\mu(A^c \cap A_{n_k}) + \mu(A) - \mu(A \cap A_{n_k}) =
\int \chi_{A^c} \cdot \chi_{A_{n_k}} d\mu + 
\mu(A) - 
\int \chi_{A} \cdot \chi_{A_{n_k}} d\mu. $$
Then, as $\chi_A = f$, the weak convergence gives that
$$ \|\chi_A - \chi_{A_{n_k}}\|_{L^2(\mu)} \longrightarrow
\int \chi_{A^c} \cdot \chi_A d\mu + 
\mu(A) - 
\int \chi_{A} \cdot \chi_A d\mu = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.
Here there is a counterexample.

We consider the measure space $([0,2\pi], \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Let $A_n = \{x \in [0,2\pi] : \sin(nx) > 0\}$.
Then, for any interval $I$, we have that
$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty} \int_{[0,2\pi]} \chi_{A_n} \cdot \chi_I d\mu =
\lim_{n\to+\infty} \int \frac{1}{2} \cdot \chi_I d\mu = |I|/2, $$
that is, the function $f \equiv 1/2$ is the weak limit of $(\chi_{A_n})_{n\geq1}$.
This implies that $f$ is the only possible $L^2$ limit of a subsequence of $(\chi_{A_n})_{n\geq1}$.
But $\|f - \chi_{A_n}\|_{L^2(\mu)} = 1/2$, so $f$ is not a $L^2$ limit of such a subsequence.